# mongodb+aggregation - автоматическое добавление полей в $project

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

используя ТОЛЬКО `aggregation` (т.е. находясь внутри `pipeline`) и `$$ROOT` создать курсор, содержащий все поля модели (автоматически) + computed fields. Разумеется, все поля модели можно перечислить ручками. Но, поскольку один скрипт будет выполнять работу с разными коллекциями, нужно чтобы поля вставлялись автоматически.

Вариант 1 (не подойдёт)

```
Коллекция.aggregate([{ 
$project:{ 
  fields:"$$ROOT", 
  computedFields: { 
    id:"$_id" 
  } 
} 
}], 
callback)
```

Не подойдёт, так как он сгенерит документы следующего типа: 
`{fields:{поля объекта}, computedFields:{id:104}}`

Нужно, чтобы получилось:
`{поле1:знач1, поле2:знач2, ... id:104}`, где поле1, поле2, ... – поля, взятые из модели коллекции автоматически.

Вариант 2 (не подойдёт):

```
var obj= {поле1:1, поле2:1, ... id:"$_id"} 
Коллекция.aggregate([{ 
  $project:obj 
}], callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

В данный момент в MongoDB не существует такой возможности. Вам нужно либо перечислить все поля заранее, либо удовольствоваться `$$ROOT` и производить изменение структуры объектов уже в коде вашего приложения.